# Why does my PS5 controller need to be re-paired to PC every time I use it?

Tags: pc, controllers

I am having a problem with my PS5 controller on PC when connecting it via Bluetooth. I have to unpair and pair it again to be able to use it.

The controller itself works really well on Bluetooth, it is just when ever I turn off my PC and later turn it on, my DualSense controller won't connect when pressing the PS button, so I have to unpair it and pair it again. This does not happen with my PS4 controller.

This is really annoying. Is there a fix for this or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If the PS4 controller is any indication, pressing the PS button doesn't turn on the controller itself (long term). It sends out a broadcast message to the last synced device to turn on. If the last known device turns on, or was already on, it responds to the controller which then turns itself on.

You can test this by having your PS controller synced to a PlayStation, unplugging the PlayStation, and pressing the PS button. You'll notice the controller turns of very quickly as it fails to communicate with its last known device.

Your PC is not able to have this communication, and so the controller doesn't complete the startup/sync process, instead requiring the PC to actively connect to the controller (which you do by pairing it).

I doubt there's going to be much support for this as the PS controllers are not made with PC compatibility in mind (as opposed to the Xbox controllers).

Comment: But the thing is my Ps4 controller automatically connects to my pc whenever i have used on my pc, even after turning my pc off and on. So why would the Ps5 controller not do it

Answer (score 0):

I have my PS5 controller paired to my PC.  I was like you and thought I had to re-pair every time since it would only give me the slower flashing blue light (not pairing) and would never go solid...

I was in the process of trying to connect my PS5 controller While reading this thread and it went solid blue (connected) on its own without me needing to re-pair.

So I guess the answer (at least now) is **"press the button and wait"**?